# Old VirtualBox version shows as Up-to-date

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

I'm running Virtualbox 4.3.18 on Windows 7.
[image]

When I try to update VirtualBox shows that it's up to date, while the latest version is 4.3.28. https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

[image]

I'm trying to update by clicking Help->Check for Updates. I've tried checking for updates with all three "Check for Updates" settings: "Stable Release Versions", "All New Releases", and "All New Releases and Pre-Releases".

[image]

Is there a better way to update VirtualBox?

Comment: Wondering if you're behind a web proxy server that might be caching results improperly for the update check.....

Comment: @DavidW do you have any idea on how to test it, or a solution if that's the case?

Comment: Unfortunately, you could probably figure out that you *are* behind a proxy server, but likely not change it. Network admins may have done that to prevent direct Internet access for security purposes. In IE, you could check Settings->Internet Options->Connections->LAN Settings and see if "Use a proxy server.." is checked, or if an "automatic configuration script" is supplied (which would probably imply but not guarantee a proxy server)

Comment: Related: [VirtualBox doesn't see the latest update](http://superuser.com/questions/843770/virtualbox-doesnt-see-the-latest-update)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same version of VirtualBox (4.3.18) on Windows, and it too doesn't detect the new version(s), even though they've been out for over a month.

Either the updater in this version is just busted, or Oracle just hasn't updated the repository that holds the versions the updater checks, or they changed its location for newer versions, or ???

To know for sure, you'd have to ask Oracle what's going on.

Best way to upgrade?  Go grab the latest version [directly from Oracle](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).